# How to occupy gridView with AJAX on Yii2?

Tags: ajax, yii, yii2, pjax

This is my first time using the Yii2 Framework, so I don't have much knowledge of the features or what it offers.

Currently I integrate Ajax as I do with all projects with script and a table that updates the data according to the option you select.

The issue is that the project occupies GridView for the tables and I was asked that all the tables were the same, ie, that the table I did now is with GridView and do not know how to implement Ajax with the Gridview.

I leave you my HTML work:

**HTML**

```
<div class="course-index container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Cursos
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="refresh-course">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody id="course-item">
                                <?php foreach ($courses as $key): ?>
                                <tr class="course-<?= $key['id'] ?> course-tr" id="<?= $key['id'] ?>">
                                <td class="name"><?= $key['name'] ?></td>
                                <td><span class="badge badge-info"><?= $key['amount'] ?></span></td>
                                <td><a title="Listar estudiantes" class="list-course" data-id="<?= $key['id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Estudiantes inscritos
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="refresh-students">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter" id="report-table">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Fecha inicio</th>
                                <th>% Completados</th>
                                <th>Tiempo realizado</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="resultData">
                            
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
initializate();
function initializate(){
    $('#report-table > tbody').empty();
    $("#course-item tr[id]").click(function(){
        var order = $(this).attr('id');
       $.ajax({
            url: '<?= Url::to(['default/load/']); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data : {id: order},
            success:function(data){
                $('#report-table > tbody').empty();
                var html = '';
                data.data.forEach(element => {
                    html += '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + element.email + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="text-align: center;">' + (element.start_date == null ? '-' : new Date(element.start_date).toLocaleDateString("en-US") ) + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="text-align: center;">' + element.percent + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + element.time + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                });
                $('#resultData').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Create two Gridviews with different dataproviders (different where clause that depend from your ajax), in gridview you have options `rowOptions` where you can set your id, set `Pjax` around two gridviews with some id and when your ajax is success you have `pjax.reload` function. When your pjax container is reloaded in the second gridview will appear your row. Or I don't understand your purpose? If it's your purpose I can show you some example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pjax. Please see documentation https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-pjax

And you can refresh your table when on clicking the refresh button with jquery

```
$.pjax.reload({container: '#boxPjax', async: false});
```

#boxPjax is Pjax container id